# Is this Doctrine query SQL injection-proof?

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, sql-injection

I saw this (Symfony) Doctrine query. Is this SQL injection-proof?

```
$input = $_GET['input'];

$query = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('id')->from('table')->where('name = ' . $input); // does Doctrine escape this input?
$statement = $query->execute();
var_dump($statement->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Does it user parameters?  No.

Comment: That looks like you are mixing a bit of QueryBuilder and a bit of traditional PDO?

Comment: Using ORMs you should play around models/repositories for such operations instead of using tables/columns in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. You have to use prepared queries with parameters. Something along thoses lines :

```
$input = $_GET['input'];

$query = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('id')->from('table')->where('name = :input'); 
$query->setParameter('input', $input)
...
```